# Request vuejs axios after auto login completed

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

How to execute all other request after auto login wass passed. Code example.

```
  axios.get('personal/' + this.$store.state.username + '/config/', {headers: { Authorization: 'Token ' + this.$store.state.idToken }})
```

Sometimes request that receive user data (username and id) have no time to passed and commit to state, and i receive an error that username is null at state.

I have solve that problem by add in login func to save username and id in localstorage, and after in try auto login i have next code:

```
tryAutoLogin ({ commit, dispatch }) {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
      if (!token) {
        return
      } else {
        commit('getToken', {
          key: token
        })
        const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId')
        const username = localStorage.getItem('username')
        if (!userId || !username) {
          dispatch('getUser')
        } else {
          commit('getUserData', {
            id: userId,
            username: username.username
          })
        }
      }
```

Is this way is ok? or there is any way to stop anny request to api, till the `dispatch('getUser')` will be passed succesfully.
example of `getUser` code:

```
getUser ({ commit, state }) {
      if (!state.idToken) {
        return
      }
      axios.get('rest-auth/user/', {headers: { Authorization: 'Token ' + state.idToken }})
        .then(res => {
          localStorage.setItem('username', res.data.username)
          localStorage.setItem('userId', res.data.pk)
          commit('getUserData', {
            id: res.data.pk,
            username: res.data.username
          })
        })
    },
```

Plz, don't be strict i am new in FE vue js:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make names of getters, actions, mutations and state more clean and obvious (getUser for getters and setUser for action, for example).

I recommend to create a separated *auth module* (place all auth logic in this module) and use it in Vuex actions or somewhere in application.

Such module should interact with the Store via Vuex getters, setters and actions (getting and setting current user auth status, for example). It makes authentification more incapsulated and clear.

In this way you'll be able to call this module's methods from any of application component and wait for the result.

In code bellow (`http_auth.js`) `this.$auth` is separated authentification module, that can set user state in Vuex and get current status. Also it use localStorage to check for saved token (user data) and tries to authorize with saved token (`tryAutoLogin` in your case). On fail, it makes redirect to login page.

```
...
methods: {
  async loadInitialData () {
    if (await this.$auth.init()) {
      axios.get('initial-data-url').then(res => ...)
    }
  }
},
created () {
  this.loadInitialData()
}
...
```

Auth methods are Promise-based, so you just can wait for resolving or rejecting before.

If you just want to use Vuex-only solution, you should use actions to call API-requests and wrap them in Promises. Also you can dispatch some action inside of other (for example, try login with saved token inside of basic login action).
Sample code (Vuex action):

```
LOAD_SOME_DATA ({ commit, state, getters }, id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!id) {
        router.push('/')
        return reject('Invalid ID passed.')
      }
      return axios.get(getters.GET_SOME_URL + id).then(response => {
        commit('PUSH_SOME_DATA', response.data)
        return store.dispatch('PROCESS_SOME_DATA').then(result => {
          return resolve(response)
        }, error => {
          console.error('Error loading some data: ', error)
          return reject(error)
        })
      }, error => {
        router.push('/')
        return reject(error)
      })
    })
  }
```

Above we wrap in promise basic api-call (`axios.get(getters.GET_SOME_URL + id)`), then process received data (`PROCESS_SOME_DATA`).
Then we can use it in router, for example (or any other part of app):

```
store.dispatch('LOAD_SOME_DATA', to.params.id).then(result => ...)
```